# Is there any way to publish messages to particular partition in kafka without using the Message key?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have millions of records each with unique identifier.

All the records are categorized by series number, let's say 10k records belong to series-1, another 10k to series-2 and so on..

Now I want to publish the all series-1 records to partition-1, all series-2 to partition-2 and so on..

To achieve this I don't want to use the message key, is there any other alternative?

*I am new to kafka, Please correct me if the question is wrong or not have proper details?*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below methods to publish a message on a specific partition

**Simple Kafka Producer**

```
/**
Creates a record to be sent to a specified topic and partition
**/
    public ProducerRecord(String topic, Integer partition, K key, V value) {
            this(topic, partition, null, key, value, null);
    }
```

Basic example to publish a message on the partition

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, <bootstrap server detail>);
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());

        //Define partition based on condition series-1 to 2 series-2 to 2
        int partition=getPartitionOnCondition.....
        String topic=""..

        Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String,String>(
                properties);
        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, partition, key, value);

        producer.send(record);
```

**Custom Partitioner**

You can also use a custom partitioner for a producer or Stream partitioner

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html

**Custom Stream Partitioner(In case you are using Kafka Stream)**

If you are using Kafka Stream. It also provides a way to enable Custom Partitioner around Kafka Stream
https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/StreamPartitioner.html

Answer (score 0):

Its better to create a `Custom Partitioner` class for your producer application.

For every record you publish with the Producer application, given custom partitioner's `partition()` method will be invoked with the messages key&value. There you may write your logic to parse the field to determine the partition number to which message should be written.

- Create a custom partitioner class similar to below,

  ```
  public class CustomPartitioner extends DefaultPartitioner {
    @Override
    public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] valueBytes, Cluster cluster) {

      Integer partitionNumber = null;

      if (valueBytes != null) {
          String valueStr = new String(valueBytes);

          /* code to extract the partition number from value*/
          /*assign partitionNumber decided based on the value*/
      }
      return partitionNumber;
    }
  }
  ```
- Assign the partitioner in your Producer class and start publishing the messages

  ```
  props.put("partitioner.class", "com.example.CustomPartitioner");
  ```